# Haskell Aeson Parse Mixed Elements Array

Tags: json, parsing, haskell, aeson

I have a json like:

```
{
  "name" : "Sam",
  "items": [ "sword", "shield", [] ]
}
```

and a data type

```
data Adventurer = Adventurer {
  name :: String,
  items :: [String]
} deriving (Generic, Show, FromJSON, ToJSON)
```

The problem is caused by the fact that the "items" field has the extra [] in the array and I get "expected String, encountered Array".

I've been trying to fix this with custom data types for the elements of the "items" array, or trying make a custom parser to ignore the extra array.

Is there a way to parse an array and only take the items which are of a certain type, dropping the rest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, we can for example first construct a function that maps `Value`s (these are JSON objects) to `Maybe String`s:

```
import Data.Aeson(Value(String))
import Data.Text(unpack)

getString :: Value -> Maybe String
getString (String t) = Just (unpack t)
getString _ = Nothing
```

We can then define a custom implementation of `FromJOSN` for `Adventurer` like:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import Data.Aeson(FromJSON(parseJSON), withObject, (.:))
import Data.Maybe(catMaybes)

instance FromJSON Adventurer where
    parseJSON = withObject "Adventurer" $ \v -> Adventurer
        <$> v .: "name"
        <*> fmap (catMaybes . map getString) (v .: "items")
```

This then yields for example:

```
Main> t = "{\n  \"name\" : \"Sam\",\n  \"items\": [ \"sword\", \"shield\", [] ]\n}"
Main> decode t :: Maybe Adventurer 
Just (Adventurer {name = "Sam", items = ["sword","shield"]})
```